# JavaScript Reload Function Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my webpage I have a piece of JavaScript to reload/refresh an iframe every three seconds.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
      reloadIFrame()
  }, 3000);

  function reloadIFrame() {
    var frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
    var len = frame.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").length;
    if ( len == 0 ){
      console.log('reloading..');
      document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
    }
  }
```

However, I don't want the function to work when there is a table present in the iframe, and it still runs when there is a table. Please let me know if there is something I am missing or your suggestions for alternative solutions.

(I do believe that the iframe which I am referencing is local on localhost:8000. I'm working with Django, if that matters, and this is part of a template.)

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal, if I may, could you help me understand why that works?

Comment: You aren't looking inside iframe window for the table

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you! Could you please tell me what I need to change to get it to look inside the window? (sorry, I'm new to JavaScript and have mostly worked only with Python, so this is a little foreign to me)

Comment: Make sure that the iframe is on the same domain, otherwise you can't get access to its internals.

Comment: @Reflective, thank you! That doesn't appear to be the case for me, though

Comment: You need to go into the `contentWindow` document and query from there

Comment: @charlietfl, it worked, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with a similar problem:

As in charlietfl's comments on the original post, the `contentWindow` was not being referenced. My code as modified below works now:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
      reloadIFrame()
  }, 3000);

  function reloadIFrame() {
    var frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
    var len = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").length;
    if ( len == 0 ){
      console.log('reloading..');
      document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
    }
  }
```

I simply needed to add `contentWindow.document` after `frame`.

Comment: You may receive protection error if not the same origin policy is followed and set correctly